# CSS sizing div in div

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to make a div that contains 3 div, and each div contain an img.
But I want to make the first div (top) have a height of 10% of the screen size, the second (middle) 60%, and third (bottom) 30%. And actually, they don't resize, and they have their full size.

My code is actually :

```
#droite
{
    display:block;          
    float:left;
    margin-left:81%;            
    width:19%;
    height:100%;
}

.logo
{
    top-margin:0%;
    height:10%;
    width:100%;
}
.DroiteMilieu
{
    top-margin:10%;
    width:100%;
    max-height:60%;
    height:100%;
}
.basDePage
{
    top-margin:80%;
    height:30%;
    width:100%;
}
img
{
    position:absolute;
}
```

(#droite is actually the big division, in which logo is the first div, droiteMilieu the second and basDePage the third one. (I will rename them soon, but I want it to work first /:) )

And the html :

```
    <div id="droite">
    <div class="logo">
        <img src="logo.png" style="max-width:100%; max-height:100%; position:relative;"</img>
    </div>
    <div class="DroiteMilieu">
        <img src="droite.PNG" style="max-width:100%; max-height:100%; position:relative;"</img>
    </div>
    <div class="basDePage">
        <img src="minimap.png" style="max-width:100%; max-height:100%; position:relative;" </img>
    </div>
</div>
```

I'm actually still bad with html/css, and I don't understand where my error is located. :/
Can someone help me?

EDIT [Problem Solve] :
A way to make it works is :
CSS :

```
html, body {
    margin: 0;
    height: 100%;
    width:100%;
}
#droite {
    display:block;          
    float:left;
    margin-left:81%;            
    width:19%;
    height:100%;
}
.logo {
    height: 10%;
    background: red;
}
.DroiteMilieu {
    height: 60%;
    background: blue;
}  
.basDePage {
    height: 30%;
    background: green;
}
#droite img {
    max-width: 100%;
    max-height: 100%;
    position: relative;
}
```

And HTML :

```
<div id="droite">
    <div class="logo">
        <img src="logo.png" style="width:100%; height:100%;">
    </div>
    <div class="DroiteMilieu">
        <img src="droite.PNG" style="width:100%; height:100%;">
    </div>
    <div class="basDePage">
        <img src="minimap.png" style="width:100%; height:100%;">
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a solution for you.

You don't need margin top and width, as they default to 100% width and stack on top.

To make the floated div to have 100% height, the body needs too, so I added that.

```css
html, body {
  margin: 0;
  height: 100%;
}
#droite {
    display:block;          
    float:left;
    margin-left:81%;            
    width:19%;
    height:100%;
}
.logo {
    height: 10%;
  background: red;
}
.DroiteMilieu {
    height: 60%;
  background: blue;
}
.basDePage {
    height: 30%;
  background: green;
}
#droite img {
  max-width: 100%;
  max-height: 100%;
  position: relative;
}
```

```html
<div id="droite">
  <div class="logo">
    <img src="logo.png">
  </div>
  <div class="DroiteMilieu">
    <img src="droite.PNG">
  </div>
  <div class="basDePage">
    <img src="minimap.png">
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: It works, except that the DroiteMilieu is still not resized, and basDePage (that is well positioned) is superimposed with DroiteMilieu

Comment: @RaphaelSchimchowitsch Are you talking about the images inside the div's? ... because the div's works and resizes.

Comment: in fact, I have my three part well positioned. But my images are larger than my div's and they doesn't fit it. It's probably the problem. Yup! If i did height:100% and width:100% it was for my images to fit in the divs.

Comment: @RaphaelSchimchowitsch I updated my answer and added back your inline style into the CSS

Comment: Well! Things are getting prettier and prettier! But there is still one prob (that I already had before). The 3 images don't have the same width anymore. The first one is larger than the second one and the last is between the twos :/

Comment: @RaphaelSchimchowitsch Use either `height: auto; width: 100%` or `height: 100%; width: auto`

Comment: I put `style="width:100%; height:100%"` in all image property. Like this, image take all the place available in the div. 
It works! Thanks for all! :)

Comment: @RaphaelSchimchowitsch You're welcome ... and please, for future users to know, accept the answer that best solve your question

Comment: Done ;) And I edited my first post to show what I've done to make it works!

Answer (score 1):

You made a few mistake, first of all, `top-margin` is not a valid property. You have to use `margin-top`.

Secondly, If you add `height: 100%;` you're asking your div to take 100% of the space of its parent (in this case, is your div taking 100% of the screen height?).

To answer your question, the way to do it, if your project only have to support CSS3, i'd suggest you to use the property: `vh` or viewport height.

Here is a little tutorial on it:
https://web-design-weekly.com/2014/11/18/viewport-units-vw-vh-vmin-vmax/

You can use it this way:

```
 .droite{
     height: 10vh; /* If you need 10% of the viewport height, then you write it this way */
  }
```

In other words, 1vh = 1% of the viewport height.

Comment: Yup, the div is taking 100% of the screen height. I will try it tomorrow and I'll let you know! 
I wasn't thinking of you replaying that fast!
Thanks a lot!

Comment: It's my pleasure :-), tell me if you need more help!

Answer (score 0):

You are setting height: 100% on .DroiteMilieu which inherits from droite and makes it 100%. That might push the others out.

Remove the max-height: 60% on .DroiteMilieu and set height: 60%; see what you get.

plus top-margin: is not a valid css attribute

```
.DroiteMilieu
{
    top-margin:10%; <---- bad css
    width:100%;        
    height: 60%; <----
}
```

Comment: I did the modification you told me to and, now i have 

` .logo
 {
  margin-top:0%;
  height:10%;
  width:100%;
 }
 .DroiteMilieu
 {
  width:100%;
  height:60%;
 }
 .basDePage
 {
  height:30%;
  width:100%;
 }`

But it still doesn't work :/

Comment: take out all  top-margin attributes

Comment: also you need to take out the position:absolute; on the images which might overwrite your flow of the elements, or make the parent div position relative.